# load qml in pyqt fron resource file

Tags: qt, pyqt, qml

I am having a doubt about pyQt resource system. I am using multiple qml files in my application hence i created a resource file of qml files named

**qml.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>BasicStatistics.qml</file>
        <file>CentralView.qml</file>
        <file>CheckBoxStyle.qml</file>
        <file>DataSummary.qml</file>
        <file>DataSummaryInfoPopup.qml</file>
        <file>DropDownItem.qml</file>
        <file>FileBrowser.qml</file>
        <file>Filters.qml</file>
        <file>GE_Button.qml</file>
        <file>GE_ToggleButton.qml</file>
        <file>GEToggleButtonStyle.qml</file>
        <file>GroupData.qml</file>
        <file>GroupedSensorModel.qml</file>
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>PageNavigator.qml</file>
        <file>Plot.qml</file>
        <file>PlotSetup.qml</file>
        <file>PlotSetup2.qml</file>
        <file>PlotSetupAdd.qml</file>
        <file>PlotSetupView.qml</file>
        <file>RadioButtonStyle.qml</file>
        <file>ReadData.qml</file>
        <file>SelectedPageModel.qml</file>
        <file>SelectedSensorModel.qml</file>
        <file>SelectedTPModel.qml</file>
        <file>TableColumn.qml</file>
        <file>TextFieldStyle1.qml</file>
        <file>TitleBar.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then it is converted into python resource file  using pyrcc command.

```
pyrcc5 -o qml_rc.py qml.qrc
```

then it is imported into main.py as

```
import qml_rc
```

then main.qml is loaded using

```
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.load(QUrl('qrc:/main.qml'))
```

but my application is crashedddd....I cannot find what the reason is.thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried it and it works correctly, you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: it works for some machines. http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/qrc-not-working-to-access-resources-td5046030.html this link helped me